# Is it possible to debug JavaScript code in Visual Studio without running a browser?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Visual Studio, at least in v2012, is supposed to have first-class support for JavaScript. However, I haven't found any "JavaScript project type", JS is not even listed as a top-level language in the File > New Project dialog etc.

JavaScript is, or at least is starting to be, much more than just a scripting language for web apps so I'm wondering **if there is a way / plugin / extension for Visual Studio that would allow me just type in some JavaScript and execute it as a language construct** (e.g., on a node console), not as part of some ASP.NET web application.

Answer (score 0):

VS2012 does have support for JavaScript, but not in a "pure JS project" sense.

If you're running VS2012 RC on Win8 Release Preview, you should see project types for Windows 8 Metro style applications implemented with JavaScript.  These types of projects are not available to create on Win7 and below (because they only run on Win8).

If you're working with JS inside web application projects, ASP.NET projects, etc. you'll see all the new rich features for JavaScript editing and debugging.